# Someone who is cunning but depicts themselves as innocent to others

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What can you call a person who is cunning but depicts themselves as innocent to others?

Comment: A "wolf in sheep's clothing" is the phrase, I believe.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj. Please provide information on how and where are you planning to use this word.

Comment: Try Machiavellian

Comment: or disingenuousness (n).

Comment: If you're open to a phrase, "faux naïf" might work.

Comment: I would say that "depicts themselves as innocent to others" is almost inherent in the meaning of "cunning".

Comment: Duplicate but I can't vote to close because no one else has suggested this, and currently there are four VTC. Duplicates (take your pick) 1. [What is an idiom/slang for “someone who pretends to be good when they're not”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not) 2. [What is a word that means “someone who pretends to be your friend but is actually your enemy?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188604/what-is-a-word-that-means-someone-who-pretends-to-be-your-friend-but-is-actuall)

Comment: 3. [Expression for a “smiling face tiger”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188010/expression-for-a-smiling-face-tiger)

Answer (score 13):

I've always called this by the old phrase

> A wolf in sheep's clothing

Answer (score 10):

**snake in the grass**   [(dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/snake+in+the+grass)

> *snake in the grass* (noun) 
>   1.   a treacherous person, especially one who feigns friendship.

Comment: While this is accurate, it doesn't seem to be in general use (at least, not in the USA).

Comment: Listen to "Don't Bring Me Down" by ELO. Not quite "current" but not "ancient" eiher. http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/electriclightorchestraelo/dontbringmedown.html

Answer (score 7):

Although many possibilities exist, I prefer using "devious" for this type of behaviour.

[MW reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devious)

> **devious**
>   : willing to lie and trick people in order to get what is wanted
>   : not straight or direct
>   : having many twists and turns

Answer (score 7):

"***Two-faced***" is a common expression that is readily understood by most.

Answer (score 5):

**sly**

Defined at [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sly):

> *adjective* 
>   having or showing a cunning and deceitful nature.
>
> "she had a sly personality" ... "sly as a fox"

This definition contains both the word *cunning* you were looking for and *deceitful* implying it fools others. So I think it would be a fitting choice.

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to a person who practices *sandbagging* as a ***sandbagger***. As indicated by the emphasized portion of the definition below, it speaks specifically to acting *innocent*.

> A person who pads a handicap or **acts as if he/she is at a lower skill level than he/she actually is** so he/she can achieve better during competition that's handicapped or by skill level.
>   <sub>[The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sandbagger)</sub>

One of the verb definitions of *sandbag* is:

> : to hide your true abilities or purpose in order to deceive people, gain an advantage, etc.
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandbag)</sub>

*Sandbagging* is a poker tactic, and is also known as *slow playing* or *trapping*. But, as seen in the definitions above, it can be used beyond the context of poker.

> **Slow playing** (also called **sandbagging** or **trapping**) is deceptive play in poker that is roughly the opposite of bluffing: betting weakly or passively with a strong holding rather than betting aggressively with a weak one.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_play)</sub>

I like to think the term derived from a sandbag looking like a pillow.

[image]<sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillow_fight)</sub>

But, alas, that is not reality. The term came from ruffians who literally took bags of sand and hit people with them. When the term was applied to poker, it was meant to denigrate a slow player, but instead it came to be a synonym for the tactic itself.<sup>[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sandbag)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A shark.  As in, a pool shark is one who pretends to be a novice in order to trick others in to placing bets at which time the shark runs the table and takes their money.

Answer (score 0):

A **fox**. As in the way the Lord Jesus used the term in the gospel of Luke, chapter 13 verses 31 to 33, about 2000 years ago.

> The same day there came certain of the Pharisees, saying unto him,
>   Get thee out, and depart hence: for Herod will kill thee.
>   And he said unto them, **Go ye, and tell that fox**, Behold, I cast out
>   devils, and I do cures to day and to morrow, and the third day I shall
>   be perfected.
>   Nevertheless I must walk to day, and to morrow, and the day
>   following: for it cannot be that a prophet perish out of Jerusalem.