# Is there a single word for someone who seems saintly but is not?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am hoping for an English word. And if no such word exist in English, is there such any such word that means the same thing or near about the same thing in other languages?

Comment: ['hypcrite'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not/42423#42423) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. As per Merriam Webster, Hypocrite: a person who puts on a false appearance of virtue or religion.         
Is there a word which says, “a person who puts on a false appearance of virtue or religion or goodness with the specific purpose of deceiving somebody (or everybody)”?       
Is my positioning of the question mark correct in the previous sentence?

Comment: In the taxonomy of non-truth situations, one who is saying something they know is false is called a liar. But if they say that X should not be done and they do X knowing all along that it is bad, then there are multiple ays of calling this - they may be deceiving you (as in a con artist), or they may be perfectly legitimate because different people have different roles and so rules apply differently. A con artist is not usually considered a hypocrite because the con's action was deliberate. Of course one can (and often is) both a hypocrite and con, but even though both are bad, a con is worse.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the word "Tartuffe" on searching the net which should serve my purpose. Only thing is it is a very less commonly used word, outside of 100000 most commonly used English words in word frequency lists.

Comment: "A Tartuffe" (a hypocrite) or "tartuffery" (hypocrisy) are synonyms, but they are very strong literary references so it has all the baggage of the work ("Tartuffe" but Molière) that comes with it.