# Another word for pretending to be something they're not

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who pretends to be something they are not? I was thinking "pretentious" but I looked up pretentious in the Merriam dictionary and think it's too strong. I want a milder term. Something that does not connote arrogance.

> 1.) self-consciously trying to present an appearance of grandeur or importance

> 2.) having a feeling of superiority that shows itself in an overbearing attitude

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/pretentious)

p.s. it doesn't have to be a single word really

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not

Comment: Can you give more details? It will depend on the nature and purpose of the pretence. For instance if they're trying to deceive someone, trick them out of money, or just prone to exaggeration and fooling around, those are very different. Likewise are they pretending to be a doctor, to be wise, to be someone else, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It really has to be 'imposter':

Noun

1. A person who practices deception under an assumed character, identity, or name.

Dictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

deceive  verb : to trick someone to believe something not real.
Fishy tricky adj

Comment: Welcome to the EL&U. If you wish to answer here, please include the research you have made in order to answer and explain why you chose to give this information.

Answer (score 0):

If they are claiming the throne, you could call them a pretender.

Comment: Short answers like this one do not contribute much. Please include definitions from reliable dictionaries and explain why you think the word you give is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed, as in 'Assumed Identity' -
from Wiktionary
2. To take on a position, duty or form
Mr. Jones will assume the position of a lifeguard until a proper replacement is found.
3. To adopt a feigned quality or manner; to claim without right; to arrogate
He assumed an air of indifference
5. To adopt (an idea or cause)

Answer (score -1):

### Dissembler

Courtesy of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissembler):

> 1: to hide under a false appearance
> *dissembling the facts*
>
> 2: to put on the appearance of
> *She lay down and dissembled sleep.*
>
> to conceal facts, intentions, or feelings under some **pretense**
> *He had dissembled about the risks involved.*